# Unable to work with web3.js on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, geth-debugging, web3-providers

This is my code:

```
   function send() {
    Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send;
    var web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");
    var data = web3.eth.getHashrate();
    alert(data);
}
```

when i run the send() function I am getting this error: "`TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function`"

Answer (score 1):

The default websocket port is 8546

You could try

```
var web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:8546");
```

Or connecting to the HTTP JSON RPC

```
var web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545");
```

Comment: changed as said still getting same type error "TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

I think here is a similar issue on github 
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1119

the idea is to use

```
Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.sendAsync = Web3.providers.HttpProvider.prototype.send
```

before creating new instance. Besides, as spoted by @cleanunicorn you should set the default ws port 8546  unless you have defined it differently when you've runed geth.

This error might be caused by a connection problem so run geth with the following options

```
--ws --wsport 8546 --wsaddr "0.0.0.0" --wsorigins="*"
```

Comment: updated the code (question) as said and still same issue

Comment: have you changed the port too?

Comment: yes, i did that too.

Comment: check my update

Comment: I am using JSON RPC now. should I change port to 8545 ?

Comment: did exactly as u said.. still no luck !

Comment: for rpc check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: thats ok .. I have run geth as said. still same error. what can i miss !